# React Hook form on Submit form data not returning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have following component :

```
    const Managerole = () => {
    
      const handleConfirmAddScreen = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      };
          
           // common component for model. AddScreen is a Dialog content component
          <ConfirmationDialog
            isOpen={isAddScreenDialogOpen}
            title="Add Screen"
            content={<AddScreen onSubmit={handleConfirmAddScreen} />}
            onClose={() => {
              setIsAddScreenDialogOpen(false);
            }}
            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
            confirmBtnText="Save"
            onConfirm={handleConfirmAddScreen}
       
  />
}
```

AddScreen component :

```
export const AddScreen = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const formProps = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  const { handleSubmit, register } = formProps;
 
  return (
   <FormProvider {...formProps}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Stack direction={"column"} gap={"2rem"}>
          <TextField
            label="Screen Name"
            required
            select
            name="screenName"
            fullWidth
            value={watch("screenName")}
            variant="outlined"
            {...register("screenName", {
              required: "This field is required.",
            })}
            margin="dense"
          >
            {screenNames?.map((item, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>
                {item.label}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
         </form>
      </FormProvider>
      ) 
     }
```

Now, when I am trying to access these form values in the `handleConfirmAddScreen` function, I am not able to get those, as I am getting only synthetic event. What can I try next here?

Comment: Please provide the implementation for ConfirmationDialog component.looks like onConfirm function is not returning proper data

Comment: Just a question I'm also new to React, shouldn't we do it like this `<form onSubmit={() => function(arguments)}>`? in AddScreen component.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma ConformationDialog component is using MUI Dialogue and it has only buttons and a click handler nothing else

Answer (score -1):

In your `AddScreen` component, `handleSubmit` function should have form data params as an argument when calling funciton like this :

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(data => onSubmit(data)) }>
</form>
```

Comment: it returns the same thing, not returning the data

Comment: Could you please let me know more details? such as git repository.

Comment: this is what I have actually.

Comment: what do you mean? Please share more details. Can you?